# how to fix text to show in tableview cell i niphone app

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am showing text in tablevew. Some text is crossing cell. I want to show text as par cell size limit and I am using customView for cell.

How will I do this. Here is part of cell initialization code.

```
 {
    .....

CustomTableCellview *cell = (CustomTableCellview *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if(cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableCellview" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = tblCell;

}

cell.titleOfPost.text = [tableList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
.......
}
```

Comment: paste the code  for CustomTableCellview where you initialize your titleOfPost.

Comment: if u want display text and height of cell is then the text then u increase height of cell or change the font size of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the frame of cell.titleOfPost to something the same size or smaller than the Cell Frame like this:

cell.titleOfpost.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,cell.frame.size.width,cell.frame.size.height);

Answer (score 0):

Set this to YES - `@property(nonatomic) BOOL adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` for the `cell.textLabel`